# Specify width of certain columns

Tags: html, css

I have a five column layout of a table and I'd like to have the following setup

C1 S1 C2 S2 C3 (content, spacer, content, ...) where C1, C2 and C3 have the same width (unknown at the moment) and S1 and S2 have a fixed width of 44 pixels. How would I specify the widths of each of the table columns? S1 and S2 are easy:

```
.spacer {
    width: 44px;
}
```

but what about the other ones?

```
.contentcolumn {
    width: ???;
}
```

The table has a dynamic width of "100%", and I'd like to avoid the trouble making it a fixed width and doing the arithmetic myself.

http://jsfiddle.net/B35Ap/

This is my HTML:

```
<div style="width: 400px">
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td id="c1">foo </td>
        <td id="s1"></td>
        <td id="c2">bar bar</td>
        <td id="s2"></td>
        <td id="c3">baz baz baz</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

And this the CSS:

```
tr {
     height: 40px;
}


#c1, #c2, #c3 {
    width: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#s1, #s2 {
    width: 44px;
}
```

Which gives me:

[image]

But I hoped for the equal width of colums 1, 3 and 5.

Comment: why not just create unique id's for each column?

Comment: what is the `spacer`? if you want to have some space between columns, you may want to try using `border-spacing` instead.

Comment: @Adjit and King King, I have revised my question. Hope it's now clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser calculates the width for

```
.contentcolumn {
    width: auto;
}
```

Since you have the table width at 100%, this should fill the columns as much as the browser can fit them.

Add an id to your table and use

```
#yourtable { display:table; table-layout: fixed;}
```

to force the columns to be equivalent (but maintain the spacer widths)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNEdb/3/)

Comment: C1, C2 and C3 should have the same width. Setting the width to auto doesn't do that (as far as I can see).

Comment: Holy cow, how are we supposed to understand the bahaviour by reading the spec (http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/table-layout):  "Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells...."

Answer (score 1):

I know that you are using a table. I did something with a list. Maybe it can help you... [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/sDc7e/5/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li>Col1</li>
  <li>Col2</li>
  <li>Col3</li> 
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    padding: 0; 
    column-count:3;
}
```

Check this link [CSS3 Multiple Columns](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

Comment: Nice! Here is a filddle with what I need, made with css3 multiple columns:  http://jsfiddle.net/8sBu8/

Answer (score 0):

You can set a specific id to each column while still keeping the class for styling.

### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="contentColumn" id="C1">C1</td>
        <td class="spacer">S1</td>
        <td class="contentColumn" id="C2">C2</td>
        <td class="spacer">S2</td>
        <td class="contentColumn" id="C3">C3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
.spacer {
    width: 44px;
}

.contentColumn {
    background-color: gray;
}

#C1 {
    width: 100px;
}
#C2 {
    width: 150px;
}
#C3 {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Another method would be to use the css selector `:nth-child` in which case your css could look something like :

```
td:nth-child(odd){
   /*here you can set the style of every odd column -- your content*/
}
td:nth-child(even){
   /*here you can set the style of every even column -- your spacers*/
}
td:nth-child(1){
   /*here you can set the style of your first column*/
}
td:nth-child(3){
   /*here you can set the style of your third column*/
}
etc...
```

Comment: But then I'd have to know the widths in advance, which I'd want to avoid.

Comment: @topskip so to be clear... despite the content of the column you want width of all columns to be equal?

Comment: yes. C1 C2 and C3 should be all exactly n pixels wide, S1 and S2 should be 44 pixels wide. And I'd like to avoid calculating n by myself.

Comment: so all you would need to do then is change your table-layout to fixed : http://jsfiddle.net/B35Ap/2/

Comment: Yes - I was unaware of `table-layout: fixed;`. Thanks!